`createWithSeed` vs using a PDA with f`indProgramAddress`

In what situations would I want to use createWithSeed function vs deriving a PDA address.

Why do the two generate different addresses


const programId = new PublicKey("4mFDYND4AVREYEJXCPhjq1LnbjELHHebJqG3NZechA7X");

const address = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([], programId)[0];
const add = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [address.toBuffer(), Buffer.from("anchor:idl")],
    programId
)[0];
// CuisJpFYLe18u7T14Z9kRKveJqFPRb3XwfR7Jh1xo8Kg

const createdAdd = await PublicKey.createWithSeed(
    address,
    "anchor:idl",
    programId
);
// 44nqWMbW4Rgm1q2VddgJJUTFZYAqHsmXETfupaKNxzDN


